# jQuery validation plugin. Validation for non form fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Ні, all!

I have a little question about jQuery.Validation plugin: - Can I complete validation for input fields that are not form fields (i.e no in the "form" tag) using jQuery.Validation plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but the field still needs to be inside a set of `<form>` tags.  However, you do **not** need to "submit" this `form` in order to check validation on the field(s) inside.  You use the `.valid()` method to check this form independently of `form` submission.

http://jsfiddle.net/9fgVN/13/

```
<form id="myNonsubmitForm" action="#">
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
</form>

<button id="myButton">Click to Check Validation Status</button>
<input type="text" id="output" />
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myNonsubmitForm").validate({
        validClass: 'valid',  // as per your configuration
        rules: {  // set rules as per your configuration
            comments: {
                required: false,
                maxlength: 10
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
             // use this to control placement of error messages
             // removal of errorPlacement handler will result in message appearing next to field automatically.
        }
    });

    $("#myButton").click(function() { // validate on button click for this example
        if($("#myNonsubmitForm").valid()){
            $('#output').val('passed');
        } else {
            $('#output').val('failed');
        };
    });

});
```

Comment: @ramb0tn1k, So why can't you use `form` tags?

Comment: You're right. I reviewed the documentation in detail and came to the conclusion that the reason why i can't use the form there is no. Thanks!